# Show a sheet in response to a drop

Tags: macos, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing drag and drop, and have a case where I need the user to decide what to do in response to a drop. So I want to bring up a sheet to ask the user for input. The problem is that the sheet doesn't appear until I drag another item to the same view. This does make sense, so I'm looking for a way to handle this differently.

The current approach looks like this (simplified):

```
struct SymbolInfo {
    enum SymbolType {
        case string, systemName
    }
    
    var type: SymbolType
    var string: String
}

struct MyView: View, DropDelegate {
    @State var sheetPresented = false
    @State var droppedText = ""
    static let dropTypes = [UTType.utf8PlainText]
    var textColor = NSColor.white
    private var frameRect: CGRect = .null
    private var contentPath: Path = Path()
    private var textRect: CGRect = .null
    @State private var displayOutput: SymbolInfo
    @State private var editPopoverIsPresented = false

    // There's an init to set up the display output, the various rects and path

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: stackAlignment) {
            BackgroundView() // Draws an appropriate background
                .frame(width: frameRect.width, height: frameRect.height)
            if displayOutput.type == .string {
                Text(displayOutput.string)
                    .frame(width: textRect.width, height: textRect.height, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(textColour)
                    .font(displayFont)
                    .allowsTightening(true)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            }
            else {
                Image(systemName: displayOutput.string)
                    .frame(width: textRect.width, height: textRect.height, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(textColour)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Retrieve state information from the environment
        }
        .focusable(false)
        .allowsHitTesting(true)
        .contentShape(contentPath)
        .onHover { entered in
            // Populates an inspector
        }
        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
            // Handle a double click
        }
        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
            // Handle a single click
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $editPopoverIsPresented) {
            // Handles a popover for editing data
        }
        .onDrop(of: dropTypes, delegate: self)
        .sheet(sheetPresented: $sheetPresented, onDismiss: sheetReturn) {
            // sheet to ask for the user's input
        }
    }

    func sheetReturn() {
        // act on the user's input
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        if let item = info.itemProviders(for: dropTypes).first {
            item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.utf8PlainText.identifier, options: nil) { (textData, error) in
                if let textData = String(data: textData as! Data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    if (my condition) {
                        sheetIsPresented = true
                        droppedText = textData
                    }
                    else {
                        // handle regular drop
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

So my reasoning is that the drop sets sheetPresented to true, but then it doesn't get acted on until the view is rebuilt, such as on dragging something else to it. But I'm still new to SwiftUI, so I may be incorrect.

Is there a way to handle this kind of interaction that I haven't found?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you could try: `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    droppedText = textData
    sheetIsPresented = true
}`

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. Maybe I need to show an alert instead of a sheet. I'll try that next week.

Comment: The concept of your code seems to work fine. But, your code is not what you have in Xcode. For example, you have `sheetPresented` and `isSheetPresented`. You also have `itemProviders(for: UTType.utf8PlainText)` without `[ ]`. I'm assuming these are a result of trying to get your code into a minimal reproducible state for a question here, which is a great idea, but it's also a signal that there could be other differences with your code.

Comment: Other things to look for: 1) make sure you're actually dropping text (and not, a URL for example). 2) Make sure your boolean condition in the drop delegate is resolving as expected.

Comment: You're correct that it's not copied from Xcode, but composed online while looking at the actual code, and hence the issues you noticed. I'll edit the code again. But as to your other comment, yes, it's text, and yes, the boolean condition is as expected.

Comment: I've considerably expanded the code example to show more context, though I don't think anything there would be relevant. Just to be weird, it seems that, after dragging text a second time and seeing the sheet, dragging text subsequent times works correctly, which implies some condition that I've missed.

Comment: Instead of including things like “my condition” can you just include a [mre] that can be copied and pasted here to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Of course, a minimal example works fine. So at least I know that what I was aiming at is possible in principle! I guess I need to add bits until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I never was able to exactly reproduce the problem, but the issue related to trying to have more than one kind of sheet that could be shown, depending on conditions. The solution was to break up the original view into a family of views that encapsulated the different behaviours, and show the appropriate one rather than try to make one view do everything.

I won't show the whole code, since it's too deeply embedded in the app, but here's a demo app that works correctly:

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

@main
struct DragAndDropSheetApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            TargetView(viewType: .normal, viewText: "A")
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .top)
            TargetView(viewType: .protected, viewText: "B")
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .top)
            TargetView(viewType: .normal, viewText: "C")
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .top)
            TargetView(viewType: .protected, viewText: "D")
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .top)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

enum ViewType {
    case normal, protected
}

struct TargetView: View, DropDelegate {
    @State private var sheetPresented = false
    @State var viewType: ViewType
    @State var viewText: String
    @State private var dropText = ""
    @State private var dropType: DropActions = .none
    static let dropTypes = [UTType.utf8PlainText]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(viewType == .normal ? .blue : .red)
            Text(viewText)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: nil, height: nil, alignment: .center)
        }
        .focusable(false)
        .allowsHitTesting(true)
        .onDrop(of: TargetView.dropTypes, delegate: self)
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetPresented, onDismiss: handleSheetReturn) {
            ProtectedDrop(isPresented: $sheetPresented, action: $dropType)
        }
    }
    
    func handleSheetReturn() {
        switch dropType {
        case .append:
            viewText += dropText
            
        case .replace:
            viewText = dropText
            
        case .none:
            // Nothing to do
            return
        }
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        if let item = info.itemProviders(for: TargetView.dropTypes).first {
            item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.utf8PlainText.identifier, options: nil) { textData, error in
                if let textData = String(data: textData as! Data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    if viewType == .normal {
                        viewText = textData
                    }
                    else {
                        dropText = textData
                        sheetPresented = true
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

enum DropActions: Hashable {
    case append, replace, none
}

struct ProtectedDrop: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var action: DropActions
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("This view is protected. What do you want to do?")
            Picker("", selection: $action) {
                Text("Append the dropped text")
                    .tag(DropActions.append)
                Text("Replace the text")
                    .tag(DropActions.replace)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.radioGroup)
            HStack() {
                Spacer()
                Button("Cancel") {
                    action = .none
                    isPresented.toggle()
                }
                .keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)
                Button("OK") {
                    isPresented.toggle()
                }
                .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Kindly add working code demonstrating your answer so others may benefit. Thanks!